# Flatpickr onChange Method does not work in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, flatpickr

Hello I am using Flatpickr on Rails 6.
I created and imported everything according to following instructions: https://github.com/adrienpoly/stimulus-flatpickr and created flatpickr_controller.js.

Flatpickr works, but i have 2 Problems.
First, only date Selection and DateRange Selection are working (haveing only a time picker, does not work). And secondly and more important the javascript Method for checking onChange, selected Dates etc. I want to retrieve the Data of the selected date and use it, so I can then show a Form field with times and then take the data and check for availability..

Any Idea why js is not working? My first console.log("Hello Flatpickr!", this.element); works..

```
import { Application } from 'stimulus'
import { definitionsFromContext } from 'stimulus/webpack-helpers'

const application = Application.start()
const context = require.context('../controllers', true, /\.js$/)
application.load(definitionsFromContext(context))
application.register('flatpickr', Flatpickr)

import Flatpickr from 'stimulus-flatpickr'

// import a theme (could be in your main CSS entry too...)
import 'flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.css'

// create a new Stimulus controller by extending stimulus-flatpickr wrapper controller
export default class extends Flatpickr {

  connect() {
    console.log("Hello, Flatpickr!", this.element);
  }
  // all flatpickr hooks are available as callbacks in your Stimulus controller
  // document.getElementsByClassName('calender_input_flatpickr').onChange


  onchange(selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
    console.log("Change works!")
    console.log('the callback returns the selected dates', selectedDates)
    console.log('but returns it also as a string', dateStr)
    console.log('and the flatpickr instance', instance)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the callbacks section in the docs - https://github.com/adrienpoly/stimulus-flatpickr#callbacks

It should work with change(){}